# How can i output the data of the state?

Tags: xml, api, react-native

I am fetching the Data of a XMLAPI and want to write the result in the state.
When i want to output the state outside of the parsestring-methode i get nothing

constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {},
            loading: true
                }
    }

```
async componentWillMount() {
    let self = this;
    fetch(furl).then(response => response.text())

        .then((response) => {

            parseString(response, function (err, result) {


                self.setState({ data: result, loading: false }, () => {

                })



            }.bind(this))

        })


        console.log(self.state.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State update are [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

When you want to print your changed state, you have to provide a callback to setState:

```
self.setState({ data: result, loading: false }, () => {
    console.log(self.state.data)
})
```